# What's the best way to group SQL results by items batch?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, I have a simple table `books`:

| author | book |
| --- | --- |
| Author-A | Book-A1 |
| Author-A | Book-A2 |
| Author-B | Book-B1 |
| Author-C | Book-C1 |
| Author-C | Book-C2 |

And I need to count books by each author, so I'll write:

```sql
select author, count(*) from books
group by author

# Author-A = 2
# Author-B = 1
# Author-C = 2
```

But now I need to count books by groups of authors:

```sql
groupA = ['Author-A', 'Author-C'],
groupB = ['Author-B']

select authorGroup, count(*) from books
group by {
  case author in groupA -> 'groupA'
  case author in groupB -> 'groupB'
} as authorGroup

# ['Author-A', 'Author-C'] = 4
# ['Author-B'] = 1
```

These groups can be different and come from another module.
What's the best way to write this requests? Maybe without union such as:

```sql
select author as 'groupA', count(*) from books
where author in { groupA }
  union
select author as 'groupB', count(*) from books
where author in { groupB }
```

because there could be a lot of groups in request (~20-30)

The problem is that these groups can be absolutely dynamic: I can request `['Author-A', 'Author-B']` in one request as one group and `['Author-B', 'Author-C']` in another.

For example, the group is not something like author's country or genre. It can be totally dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to `JOIN` on to a mapping table, which can be an in-line-view if need be *(though I recommend an actual table, which can be indexed)*.

```
WITH
  author_group AS
(
  SELECT 'Author-A' AS author, 'Group-A' AS group_label
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Author-B' AS author, 'Group-B' AS group_label
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Author-C' AS author, 'Group-A' AS group_label
)
SELECT
  author_group.group_label,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  books
INNER JOIN
  author_group
    ON author_group.author = books.author
GROUP BY
  author_group.group_label
```

Similar results can be achieved with `CASE` expressions, but it doesn't scale very well...

```
WITH
  mapped_author AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    CASE author
      WHEN 'Author-A' THEN 'Group-A'
      WHEN 'Author-B' THEN 'Group-B'
      WHEN 'Author-C' THEN 'Group-A'
    END
      AS author_group
  FROM
    books
)
SELECT
  author_group,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  mapped_author
GROUP BY
  author_group
```

Comment: Interesting solution! These groups can be generated by programming code in requests, so that's not a problem if concerns about scaling are not about request performance

Comment: @looken-tooken Both options can be written by code. If you're not sure how, open another question showing your source data structures, showing your desired sql statement, and stating what programming language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a new table that show in what group is the author.

Later you just count

Like this:

```
select distinct a.group_auth, count(a.book) over (partition by a.group_auth) 
from
(select 
       case when b.Author in [groupA] then 'groupA', 
             when b.Author  in [groupB] then 'groupB' 
        end case as group_auth,
        b.book as book
from books b
) as a
;
```

Comment: The problem is that these groups can be absolutely dynamic. I can request `['Author-A', 'Author-B']` in one request as one group and `['Author-B', 'Author-C']` in another.

For example, the group is not a tag like author's country or genre. It can be dynamic in different requests.

But thanks for idea with `over` and `partition by`!

Comment: Using `DISTINCT` together with a window function gives the same result as `GROUP BY`, but is strictly more costly to execute.